# About removing old kernels

Tags: kernel, uninstall

I am trying to remove my used kernels since my /boot is going low. Here I have a chicken and egg problem.

First I try to remove the kernel with command:
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-... and sudo apt-get -y purge...

It gave me error that
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Then I run apt-get -f install, then got the error that /boot has no space left.

So how can first release some space under /boot? I don't want to rudely delete the files under /boot anyway.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? eg. **13.10**, **13.04 LTS** *It is slightly different in latest versions.*

Answer (score 0):

Manually remove the kernels with dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -P kernel_name
```